# Как написать проверку какая из интрукции работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, синтаксис, try-catch

Как написать проверку какая из инструкции работает.
Необходимость возникла в работой с selenium, чтобы не ждать каждую загрузку браузера и выполнения одного поиска элемента, а потом его переделывать помногу раз. И как правильно можно было бы задать такой вопрос тут (правильно сформулировать)?

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("passwd-id")
#element = driver.find_element_by_name("passwd")
#element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='passwd-id']")
```

чтобы каждую команду при каждом запуске не раскомментировать, как это сделать проще?

Answer (score 0):

Мысли такие по этому поводу

```
proverka = 0
try:

     driver.find_element_by_id("passwd-id").click()
     proverka = 1
     print ('выполнил команду 1')
except:
     print ('ошибка команда 1')
if proverka == 0:
     try:
          element = driver.find_element_by_name("passwd").click()
          proverka = 1
          print ('выполнил команду 2')
     except:
          print ('ошибка команда 2')
if proverka == 0:
     try:
          element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='passwd-id']").click()
          proverka = 1
          print ('выполнил команду 3')
     except:
          print ('ошибка команда 3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Я посоветую вам в таком случае использовать библиотеку lxml. Вам понадобиться один раз сохранить html код командой `browser.page_sorce` и потом искать сколько угодно элементов:

```
from lxml import html

browser.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(browser.page_source)
browser.quit()
element = tree.xpath('xpath')
print(element)
```

То есть, вы загружаете страницу, сохраняете её HTML код в переменную, и ищите нужный вам элемент уже по "текстовому файлу".

Но такой подход вам не подойдёт, если к примеру вам нужно использовать `.click()` по найденному элементу